# Why can't I access my viewmodel in my user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, user-controls, view

I've tried this in a couple different ways:

1:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyNameSpace.MyModel>" %>
```

2:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNameSpace.MyModel" %>
```

But no matter what I do, I don't have access to `this.Model` or anything else I'd expect to see. Other controls and pages in the project are able to access these, and none of the developers are able to tell me why theirs can and my can't. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've created a few controls and pages since then. Sometimes, intellisense finds `this.Model` with no problem. It also finds things like `Html.RenderPartial()` and various other goodies that it's supposed to find. So, for those of you who would tell me that intellisense doesn't work in views, you're wrong. IT DOES. But it's not consistent amongst all views. As far as I and any other developers can tell, I'm not doing anything different. Things I've tried:

- Close the solution
- Delete post build folders
- Reopen solution
- Rebuild, either regular or analysis build

Sometimes those steps fix the problem, but for some controls, I just can't make the red squiggley lines go away! It's not the end of the world, since it doesn't produce runtime errors, but I want to understand what's going on here. Surely somebody has experienced this and has learned the source of the problem.

Comment: The first definition is correct. How are you passing the view model? What do you mean that you cannot access it? Are you getting an error message or something? Be a bit more descriptive please.

Comment: You're missing an angle bracket in 1. Should have a `>` at the end, after `MyModel`. Not sure if that's a typo.

Comment: Your imported namespace has the exact same name as your generic model class in the "inherits" declaration.  The import should just be "MyNameSpace".

Comment: Or if you really do have a namespace that is the same name as your class, you really should change that. Eric Lippert has a great blog post on the whys for that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: When I say I can't access it, I mean it doesn't appear on the intellisense dropdown.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: Yes, it's just a typo. I'm surprised you got 4 up votes for that.

Comment: @Steve Danner: I tried it with just the namespace too.

Comment: @Samo, do you really trust Intellisense? I don't. What happens when you run your application? That's the real thing. Two possibilities: you will get an error which you would post here if you expect answers or your application will simply run fine and you will never ever trust Intellisense, syntax highlighting, ... in the future.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: It doesn't produce runtime errors. What it does produce is red squiggly lines and code analysis errors. I'm not allowed to check in code that has code analysis errors.

Comment: @Samo, Intellisense in views is crap. Never trust it. And that's a conclusion I've reached after using Visual Studio for many many years. And do you really use Intellisense as a code analysis tool? That's not serious.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Intellisense has nothing to do with the code analysis tool. The code analysis tool analyzes the view and doesn't recognize the properties I've tried to access. While this is similar to what intellisense does, one tool is not using the other. Furthermore, the intellisense is working fine in other views (as I mentioned in my question) but the other developers can't figure out what the difference is, and neither can I.

Comment: @Samo, then I wouldn't trust this code analysis tool. Because trusting and relying on something that doesn't work is not good. And the reason is, well, your code works, whereas this tool tells you it doesn't, so ... :-)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I understand your point but I think my question is still legit. It's not just the model. For example, in some controls/pages, if I import `System.Web.Mvc.Html`, intellisense will give me `Html.RenderAction`. But in the pages and controls where I'm having troubles with my model, intellisense doesn't pick these up either. There HAS to be something I'm doing, some stupid little detail that's hidden in my underlying folder structure, post build, or something. I need this question answered. "Don't worry about it" is not acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try adding it to the web.config :

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyHtmlHelperLibrary.HtmlExtensions"/>
    <add namespace="MyOtherNamespace"/>
  </namespaces>
```

Comment: Products don't have access to Platform's Web.config. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Samo - ? Your comment doesn't make sense? are you saying you don't have physical access to the web.config file?

Comment: Yes. My product is built on a solution that is meant to serve as a platform for multiple products. Products aren't allowed to touch any of the code in the Platform solution.